# Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent

Tags: android, android-edittext

Please help me. I was struggling with this issue since past one day. I dont know how to resolve this.While I try to type any character in edittext,keys are typed but typing character was not set on the required field. while I try to set the character using settext() in Text change listener,it throughs stackoverflow error. 
Note: It was happend only in 4.4 kitkat(mentioned micromax device) but while checking in nexus it was working fine)

```
 edtPwd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_1);
    edtPwd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_2);
    edtPwd3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_3);
    edtPwd4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_4);
    edtPwd1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            edtPwd1.setFocusable(true);
            edtPwd1.setCursorVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    edtPwd2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            edtPwd2.setFocusable(true);
            edtPwd2.setCursorVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    edtPwd3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            edtPwd3.setFocusable(true);
            edtPwd3.setCursorVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    edtPwd4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            edtPwd4.setFocusable(true);
            edtPwd4.setCursorVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    edtPwd1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.e("sdfsadfsdfsdf------", "-------" + s);
           // edtPwd1.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //edtPwd1.setText(s);
            edtPwd1.clearFocus();
            edtPwd2.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    edtPwd2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.e("efasdhfhsldf-----", "------1" + s);
            edtPwd2.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //edtPwd2.setText(s);
            edtPwd2.clearFocus();
            edtPwd3.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    edtPwd3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.e("efasdhfhsldf-----", "------2" + s);
            edtPwd3.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //edtPwd3.setText(s);
            edtPwd3.clearFocus();
            edtPwd4.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    edtPwd4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.e("efasdhfhsldf-----", "------4" + s);
            edtPwd4.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //edtPwd4.setText(s);
            if (!edtPwd4.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                edtPwd4.clearFocus();
                edtPwd1.clearFocus();
                edtPwd2.clearFocus();
                edtPwd3.clearFocus();
                edtPwd1.setFocusable(false);
                edtPwd2.setFocusable(false);
                edtPwd3.setFocusable(false);
                edtPwd4.setFocusable(false);
                edtPwd1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                edtPwd2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                edtPwd3.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                edtPwd4.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                edtPwd1.setCursorVisible(false);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtPwd4.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
    edtPwd2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (edtPwd1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edtPwd2.clearFocus();
                    edtPwd1.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    edtPwd3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (edtPwd1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edtPwd3.clearFocus();
                    edtPwd1.requestFocus();

                } else if (edtPwd2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edtPwd3.clearFocus();
                    edtPwd2.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    edtPwd4.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (edtPwd1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edtPwd4.clearFocus();
                    edtPwd1.requestFocus();

                } else if (edtPwd2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edtPwd4.clearFocus();
                    edtPwd2.requestFocus();

                } else if (edtPwd3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edtPwd4.clearFocus();
                    edtPwd3.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Sorry for my poor english and thanks in advance

Comment: have you check text color? because it is odd that text is not set. it will set automatically in default functionality.

Comment: ya i checked and also i changed text color. typed character was not entered in edititext

Comment: add your code please.

Comment: ok wait i will add

Comment: first of all please comment all you listener and try issue is in a way you are using this listener they are conflicts with each other.

Comment: ok wait i will try and let u know

Comment: sorry bro, now also having same issue

Comment: @palanivelraghul first of all by default in all android versions, EditText will get focused when touching the same and user will be allowed to enter text. Unless and until these features are not modified by user. Cursor visibility and focusing on the touched EditText need not be done. Remove all those and try. More over your requirement is not clear

Comment: @Stallion Thanks bro i tried by removing all my listeners, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextChangeListner` will create complexity in populating the entered text which depends on which all methods are overridden. Moreover all android versions by default will handle focusing on EditText once user presses. Virtual keyboard will also be available unless and until developer has not modified the default features through code.

First of all in order to verify whether you are able to enter text in EditText only keep the following and comment all other implementations.

```
edtPwd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_1);
edtPwd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_2);
edtPwd3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_3);
edtPwd4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_pwd_4);
```

Now if you want to process the text entered by one edit text on the fly, you can try the following sample. This will copy the text entered from one edit text to other through a handler

```
EditText text1;EditText text2;
 StringBuffer previousChar=new StringBuffer();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if(!previousChar.toString().equals(s.toString())){
                            Message msg=new Message();
                            msg.obj=s.toString();
                            localHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                            previousChar=new StringBuffer(s.toString());
                            Log.i("TAG", "TextEntered = "+s);
                        }
                    }
                });}
```

Declare a Handler to get the string entered

```
private Handler localHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            String value=(String)msg.obj;
            text2.setText(value);
        }
    };
```